# Какую книгу по C# читать после книги Шилдта C#. Полное руководство?

Tags: c#, книги

Какую книгу по C# читать после книги Шилдта C#. Полное руководство?

Comment: ИМХО, надо делать упор на написание работающих приложений, а не на чтение over9000 книжек.

Comment: если писать работающие приложения без чтения книжек, работать они будут плохо, сопровождаться ещё хуже, а расширяться не будут вообще! а код в них будет сущим адом для посторонних людей, а через некоторое время и для автора тоже.

Comment: Я не писал, что надо делать приложения без чтения книжек. Я хотел сказать, что практика не должна быть оторвана от теории.

Comment: а кто вам сказал, что у меня практика оторвана от теории?

Comment: оффтопик/
Уважаемый @ArniLand у Вас очень маленький процент принятых ответов, может ты Вы будете все таки помечать верные ответы или закрывать их?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Классические книги по программированию](http://sergeyteplyakov.blogspot.com/2010/03/blog-post.html).

Comment: какую именно книгу по C# читать после Шилдта? Троелсена? Вопрос не по теме немного. Шилдта с Бучем параллельно читать можно?

Comment: ни одна книга не помешает вам в чтении другой.

Comment: с вами можно проконсультироваться по литературе за пределами форума чтобы не плодить кучу тем?

Comment: да чего там консультироваться, читайте Рихтера и Албахари, для изучения C#, Банду Четырх - Паттерны проектирования, Макконела и Фаулера, чтобы говнокод не писать, остальное по ссылке в ответе.

Answer (score 1):

Мое мнение что Шилдт хорошая база. После нее уже можно браться за что то реальное. Например пройти курсы в какой-нибудь компании или подключиться к open-source разработке.